# Jquery.Ajax GET doesn't work in visual studio but can run in Firebug

Tags: jquery, ajax, visual-studio-2010

My ASPX code :

```
 $("#btn01").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Default4.aspx",
                    data: "name=iswanto&time=81pm",
                    success: function (data) {
                        //called when successful
                        alert("success");
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        //called when there is an error
                        console.log(e.message);
                        alert("failed");
                    }
                });
            });
```

Default4.aspx code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s1 = Request["name"] + "";
    string s2 = Request["time"] + "";

    File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\test.txt", new string[] { s1, s2});     
}
```

When i run from Visual Studio, the file is not generated, but when i run the script in Firebug console, the file is generated.

I tried to set the breakpoint in the `Page_Load` code, but it seems doesn't hitted when i run the website.

My question is why my jQuery.Ajax not working when I run the code from Visual Studio?

Comment: One thing to know is that this is very non-standard practice. Web service methods should be just that: their **own** methods. Having your logic inside the `Page_Load` method is a bad idea -- it's an automatically wired-up event handler and shouldn't be used for anything other than that. You should create a separate static method decorated with the `[WebMethod]` attribute and call that instead (`url: "Default4.aspx/YourMethod"`). That method should have `name` and `time` parameters so you don't have to manually retrieve the variables from the `Request` object.

Comment: i think we need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOL, I just found it. In my aspx i have this form:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn01" />
 </form>
```

I need to prevent postback in my jQuery code:

```
       $("#btn01").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "Default4.aspx",
                data: "name=iswanto&time=81pm",
                success: function (data) {
                    //called when successful
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    //called when there is an error
                    console.log(e.message);
                    alert("failed");
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: You can't use `$("#btn01")` unless you have `ClientIDMode="Static"` for your button control.